# Peg Puzzle formatting output

Tags: c, format, logic

I'm trying to create a peg jump puzzle and I'm doing the format specifiers and I realize the algorithm is not done yet, but can someone explain why my condition is being ignored? It's running format specification, even when column is more than one. For example, each '+' for every row after the first one in the peg jump puzzle game has 7 spaces before each column's '+', when I want only the very first column to have format specification and then each row thereafter have descending spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    //variables for pieceboard

    char p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9;
    int row = 1;
    int column = 1;

    p1 = 'o';
    p2 = p3 = p4 = p5 = p6 = p7 = p8 = p9 = '+';

    for ( row =1 ; row <= 5; row++ ){
        for ( column = 1; column <= row; column++ ) {
            if ( row == 1 ) {
                printf("%+8c", p1);
            }
            else if( row > 1 && column == row )
                printf("%+7c", p2);

        printf("\n");
}
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you come across arrays yet?  The use of `p1` .. `p9` strongly hints at an array. The fact that you don't really use `p3` .. `p9` hints at trouble to come.

Comment: Thanks but we can't use arrays for this project :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something looks odd with your curly braces. I usually include curly braces even for single line else statements to make the code more clear.

Try surrounding your else if() code block with {} braces and recompile. See if that helps.

Actually, it looks like you are missing an ending curly brace for one of your for loops.